# Adding HTML tags to Scala Play output

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to bold certain phrases in a Play template output, but all it does is output the  HTML tag:

```
@signs.map {sign =>
            <tr>
            <td>@sign(2).replaceAll(phrase, "<b>" + phrase + "</b>") <strong>(@sign(0) : @sign(1) - @sign(3))</strong> </td>
            </tr>
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplates#Escaping:

> ### Escaping
>
> By default, dynamic content parts are escaped according to the
>   template type’s (e.g. HTML or XML) rules. If you want to output a raw
>   content fragment, wrap it in the template content type.
>
> For example to output raw HTML:
>
> ```
> <p>
>   @Html(article.content)
> </p>
> ```

Comment: Not following how this relates to the issue I am running into. Can you please explain.

Comment: `sign(2).replaceAll(phrase, "<b>" + phrase + "</b>")` is a string containing HTML. Twirl (the Play template engine) escapes HTML by default. Wrap it in `@Html(...)` to write the raw string into the view.

Comment: still not following. can you please give an example?

Comment: `@Html(sign(2).replaceAll(phrase, "<b>" + phrase + "</b>"))`